# How to get the nivo slider to show excerpt

Tags: excerpt

I'm trying to embed the nivo slider into a wordpress theme so each slide shows a set of recent image pots and excerpt. At this moment I can get it to show the images but not the post excerpt.

```
<div id="slides">
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=5&category_name=featured'); while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nivoimage', true); ?>" alt="" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
</a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<div class="clear">
```

Ideally I'd like the excerpt to wrapped in a div so I can style it in css. Does anyone have any ideas?

I should maybe also mention that I'm using the mimbo theme and that doesn't want to accept any kind of news slider plugin.

Thanks,

---

*Editors Note: Links to template pastes and such:*

- [index](http://pastebin.com/vE9hvT37)
- [header](http://pastebin.com/5Rq9na0d)
- [`get_template_part();`-slides](http://pastebin.com/cuhHWMHG)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear if your saying you can call the excerpt but it's not showing up or if you don't know the function to show the excerpt.

If it's the former it might be a CSS issue, if the latter the following should do the trick:

```
<div class="content-summary">
     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
```

You can read more about [the_excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) function in the WordPress Codex.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan,

It's more former, I'm not sure how to integrate the_excerpt part into the above code so that the excerpt changes along with the slide?

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without seeing the relevant javascript & css. Just wrapping the link, image and excerpt in a div with the relevant class (maybe `.slide`?) should be all you need to do.

Comment: ok cool, here's my index page [link]http://pastebin.com/vE9hvT37 the header [link]http://pastebin.com/5Rq9na0d  and the get_template_part slides [link]http://pastebin.com/cuhHWMHG

Comment: and the template part is called jFlowControl it should refer to nivo slider but I haven't got round to renaming it yet.